# Highlighting (`hilight`) all messages from a specific channel

Tags: irssi

Is there anyway to highlight all text from specific channels? I have a lot of low-traffic channels that I want to grant special attention to. I want irssi to really scream if there is traffic on these channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most effective way I could find was

```
/hilight -channels #chan -regexp .
```